# Телеграм граббер не работает на python, как починить?

Tags: python

Делаю впервые на питоне граббер по урокам в ютубе. Может кто тоже делал. Вылезает такая ошибка. Код подтверждения на аккаунт в телеге прилетел, при попытке создать соединение - пишет вот это. Как чинить, не подскажите?

```html
python grab.py
Попытка запустить телеграм граббер
'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 242, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\grab.py", line 31, in new_channel_post
    post_id = add_post_to_db(message)
  File "C:\Users\User\grab.py", line 55, in add_post_to_db
    'message_id': message.message_id,  # внутренний id сообщения
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас библиотека pyrogram, то ошибку знаем, проходили)

Ошибка в строке 55, измените с `message.message_id` на `message.id`